# Set other video on video end (cv2)

Tags: python, opencv, video

I am trying to set other video on video end in cv2.

I expected it to set other video (that i provided), and the actual results was none. The window just closes and displays an error in the command line.

The error is:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

I tried to do it by re-defining the cap variable.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        cap = cv.VideoCapture('video2.mp4')
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set the the `cap` for video2.mp4 you will need to read the first frame of video2.
The frame object is still the same (invalid one) from the previous `cap.read()`
You shuld also release the old capture object before opening the new one.
Try the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        cap.release() # release old Capture object
        cap = cv.VideoCapture('video2.mp4')
        ret, frame = cap.read() # read first frame of new video
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```